# On inverse matrices of linear combination of permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Consider the subset $T$ of the set of $5\times 5$ real matrices consisting of the matricecs of the following form:
>   $$ \begin{pmatrix}
> a&b&c&d&e\\
> e&a&b&c&d\\
> d&e&a&b&c\\
> c&d&e&a&b\\
> b&c&d&e&a\\
> \end{pmatrix}. $$
>   Let $A$ be an invertible matrix in the subset $T$. Show that the inverse of $A$ is also in $T$.
>
> Hint: Express $A$ as $aI+bZ+cZ^2+dZ^3+eZ^4$, where $Z$ is a permutation matrix of order $5$.

---

My solution:

Set $$B=x_1I+x_2Z+x_3Z^2+x_4Z^3+x_5Z^4$$ where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ are indeterminates. We want to show that $AB=I$ has a solution in $\mathbb R$, i.e.,(After a relatively long time of expansion...) the following set of linear equations has a solution:

$$ A^{T}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)^{T}=(1,0,0,0,0)^{T} $$
where $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a&b&c&d&e\\
e&a&b&c&d\\
d&e&a&b&c\\
c&d&e&a&b\\
b&c&d&e&a\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ is invertible. Then clearly $$ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)^{T}=(A^{T})^{-1}\cdot (1,0,0,0,0)^{T} $$ is a solution. And we are done.

---

I am asking for other methods since I don't think mine is good enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $A^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $A$. Therefore, in your case, $A^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $Z$. However, by Cayley-Hamilton theorem, the characteristic polynomial of $Z$ (which is a monic polynomial of degree $5$) annihilates $Z$. Therefore, by factor theorem, $A^{-1}$ can be written as a polynomial in $Z$ of degree $\le4$ and the result follows.

Comment: Awesome! Never aware of the use of Cayley-Hamilton theorem expressing inverse matrices as a polynomial of matrices. Thank you!

Comment: @Bach By the way, matrices in the form of $A$ are known as [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). The computer science or engineering guys will also recognise the product of a circulant matrix and a vector as a convolution.

Comment: Here we have $Z^5=I$ I wonder how much this condition could be generalized assuming that $Z$ is any form of matrix. Certainly it could be also  $ Z^5 =aI $  Can we extend the condition broader?

Comment: @Widawensen Yes, of course. Please see my new edit.